# Unable to sort a list of dictionaries by position

Tags: python

I'm learning python and doing an online exercise.

My current goal is to sort a list of dictionaries:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr=[]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        arr.append({name: score})
        
    print(arr)
    print(sorted(arr,key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20240211/09/34/hackerrank-1e461b8e0b66f9b6cec57a2d76f20107/code/Solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(sorted(arr,key=lambda x: x[1]))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/submission/20240211/09/34/hackerrank-1e461b8e0b66f9b6cec57a2d76f20107/code/Solution.py", line 9, in <lambda>
    print(sorted(arr,key=lambda x: x[1]))
                                   ~^^^
KeyError: 1
```

Why is it causing this error, is there some underlying fact about dictionaries that I am missing? How do I resolve it?

Comment: See [link](https://realpython.com/sort-python-dictionary/) to better understand. x[1] is the value of a Dictionary item with key 1; which is not what you intend.

Comment: Thank you for this guidance. I will read up on it.

Comment: `arr.items()` transform the dict into a list of tuples and then `[1]` works

Answer (score 1):

For sorting the array of dictionary using labmda:
sorted(ARRAY_NAME, key = lamda x: x["KEY"])
where **KEY** should be replace by your dictionary key.

Example:

```
arr=[{"name": "Tom", "score": 4.5}, {"name": "Jerry", "score": 2.5}]  
   
#Sorting arr with respect to name  
sorted(arr, key = lamda x: x["name"])  
  
#Sorting arr with respect to score  
sorted(arr, key = lamda x: x["score"])
```

In your case

```
arr = [{"Tom": 4.5}, {"Jerry": 5.6}]  
  
#Sorting arr with respect to name  
sorted(arr, key = lamda x: list(x.keys()))  
  
#Sorting arr with respect to score  
sorted(arr, key = lamda x: list(x.values()))
```